# Save word file as html in java

Tags: java, command-line, macros, ms-word, doc

I try to save a word file as html using java. I save a word file as xml and its working for me

```
Runtime rt1 = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt1.exec("C:/Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office12/WINWORD.EXE /msaveasxml C:/myfolder/AB_00040.doc");
```

It save my doc file as xml file in the specific folder C:/myfolder and I view that xml file at  C:/myfolder/AB_00040.xml

If i want to save the same file as html what can i do. Any one help

```
rt1.exec("C:/Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office12/WINWORD.EXE /msaveas??? C:/myfolder/AB_00040.doc");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is more of a MS Word question than java. Have you tried "msaveashtml"?

Comment: This may help you...http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-word-2007-HP010164010.aspx

Comment: This one too...http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210565

Comment: @AnuragKapur yes i try but it wont work

Comment: You've got to create a macro - that's what /m is used for.  There's a macro that's been created in your AB_00040.doc that's called "saveasxml".  Create another one called "saveashtml" in the document and then you should be able to use /msaveashtml.  Check out the links I posted and it will give you further guidance

Comment: As an alternative, instead of trying to automate Word, you could use docx4j. Automating Word may be necessary though, if your documents use esoteric features.

Comment: @ZackMacomber thanks for your help I try to use a macro for that function

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer with the hint of Zack Macomber i use a macro for convert word file to html file. I give the coding for that macro. Save the name of macro as "saveashtml"

```
Sub saveashtml()
Dim xmlname As String
xmlname = ActiveDocument.FullName
xmlname = Replace(xmlname, ".docx", ".html", , , vbTextCompare)
xmlname = Replace(xmlname, ".doc", ".html", , , vbTextCompare)
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=xmlname, FileFormat:=wdFormatHTML, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False
Application.Quit
End sub
```

You can execute this macro by

```
Runtime rt1 = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt1.exec("C:/Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office12/WINWORD.EXE /msaveashtml C:/myfolder/AB_00040.doc");
```

saveasxml macro coding

```
Sub saveasxml()
Dim xmlname As String
xmlname = ActiveDocument.FullName
xmlname = Replace(xmlname, ".docx", ".xml", , , vbTextCompare)
xmlname = Replace(xmlname, ".doc", ".xml", , , vbTextCompare)
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=xmlname, FileFormat:=wdFormatFlatXML, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: I am using your solution in a web application where user upload a word document in client and I invoke winword with macro to convert to html on server side. But there is a problem with this approach. If word document is corrupted, or read-only etc, and when server run winword command, winword prompt like "Doc is corrupted, Do you still want to open?", "Doc is Read-only, Do you want to open?" etc. and hangs forever in memory, because winword is waiting for an user input and program cannot provide that input. Do you know any solution to this?

Comment: use ahk or pywinauto or locate functions of pyautogui