# Importing/Copying and Pasting Word Document to HTML

Tags: php, html, ms-word

We need to import OR copy and paste word documents and convert them to HTML ready data.

Here's my thoughts:

- collect the text with `file_get_contents`
- apply the function `nl2br`

However, it does not account for **bold** and other text formatting.

Also, there are several microsoft characters that we shouldn't require.

What is a good strategy for word imports into beautiful HTML?

Comment: Checkout using CKEditor on your form. There is a paste from word feature.

Comment: I concur with justin. do not even start trying to clean that on your own. bottom line is word is not in any way html. Hoping it will be "beautiful" depends entirely on how many of the zillions of pitfalls the developer has accounted for in their word parsing. word2cleanhtml is your best bet. With word, as soon as you think you got it all, they either change their crap or someone uploads another file with a billion other unforseen unique characters.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't try to tackle all of this on your own.  [word2cleanhtml.com](http://word2cleanhtml.com/) looks like it will suit your needs and may have an API offering soon.

However, it appears that you can use Word itself from the command line to convert your document for you.  This will, of course, require that MS Word is installed on your PHP server.

```
shell_exec("C:/Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office12/WINWORD.EXE /msaveashtml C:/path/to/your.doc");
```

The above code uses the macro defined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13800749/126562) to a similar question.  You will need to copy the the saveashtml macro from that answer and add it to Word.

Comment: Not really: `Currently we don't offer API access to this service.`

Comment: I suppose I should have actually hone to the API page :/

Comment: API or not, OP asked for import OR copy paste, so I still give credit

Comment: I agree copy/paste is off topic but it is sort of acceptable if OP is asking for something like "is it possible" or in this case trying nl2br and realizing that won't cut it. While it would be awesome if someone here would provide a full word parsing library, it is more realistic to point to a service that already exists that can offer at least something to future readers who just require the parsing, whether or not it is programatic.

Comment: A non copy/paste solution has been provided.