# Converting docx to html using winword,exe programatically

Tags: html, docx

I need to convert my DOCX file to HTML. I don't want to do it manually through MS Word. Instead using WinWord.exe, I want to convert it through a program. Can someone tell me how can I convert the file through a program ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save word file as html in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767796/save-word-file-as-html-in-java)

Comment: Most likely a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767796/save-word-file-as-html-in-java